# Passing value by using Context API and useContext (React js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, use-context

I want to pass value of **customerFlag**  which i have declared in **Login.jsx** component  and want to access that value in **Header.jsx**. I am using **Context API** and **useContext**. Basically here i am passing value between two components you can say sibling components. but **problem** is i am getting customerFlag value is **undefined** under the **UserContext.Provider value={customerFlag}** tag. Kindly correct me if i am doing it wrong. I am a beginner in react js.

**Login.jsx**

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';

      //Creating Context API
        const UserContext = createContext(null);
        .
        .
        .
        } else {
    
                 customerFlag='customer';
                 window.alert('Login successfull');
                 history.push('/home');
    
                }

return (
        <>
            
            {/* Providing the context to Header*/}

            <UserContext.Provider value={customerFlag} >
                <Header />
            </UserContext.Provider>

        </>
        )
```

**Header.jsx**

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react';
import {UserContext} from './Login';

const Header = () => {
    
    const context = useContext(UserContext)
    console.log(context);

return ();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`customerFlag='customer';` is not known in lifecycle of React component. It means if `customerFlag` changes later, your **Context** won't notice.

You'll need to use **state** for customer flag. e.g.:

```
const [cusomterFlag, setCustomerFlag] = useState('');

// ...

if(...) {
  // ...
} else {
  setCustomerFlag('customer');
  window.alert('Login successfull');
  history.push('/home');
}
```